# AVHRR 1 km Coterminous US Server Location

Tags: ndvi, server

I want to download a signficiant amount of AVHRR data directly from a FTP server... the problem is I'm having a really hard time finding the server location.  I don't want to use EarthExplorer because this is very inefficient.  Does anyone know where the server for the AAUS dataset can be found?

https://lta.cr.usgs.gov/NDVI

Answer (score -1):

@Emily: I'm not sure if this is the data set you're after, but I believe you can download the GIMMS AVHRR Global NDVI from:

ecocast.arc.nasa.gov/data/pub/gimms/3g.v0/